# About minimal prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Given a commutative ring A. Prove that the set of prime ideals in A
>   has minimal element with respect to inclusion.

I try to apply Zorn's lemma to prove above problem, but I can't find the way to construct a lower bound for any chain in prime ideals set. Please give me an idea to construct this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you consider an intersection over all the ideals in the chain? Also, there is a similar argument that every commutative ring has a maximal ideal; it also uses the Zorn lemma, but with the union over all the ideals in the chain as an upper bound

Comment: @G. Chiusole I try to apply the same way as you have said, but the intersection of prime ideals is not a prime ideal (radical of $A$ as example), so i'm stuck there

Comment: The intersection of arbitrary prime ideals is not necessarily prime, that is true. But you aren't taking an arbitrary set of prime ideals. A chain is very special, just argue from first principles.

Comment: I added a 3rd dupe link - which includes an excerpt of a nice expostion by Kaplansky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Consider the intersection of the prime ideals in a *chain* (the set of all prime ideals  is not a chain, in general) and  prove the contrapositive: if $x$ and $y$ do not belong to the intersection, neither does $xy$.